# Why is this not LL(1) grammar?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, nlp, grammar

S -> 1S2 | S0 | epsilon

I thought it would be LL(1) because it is possible to determine.

For example if the next input symbol was 0 i'd know it was S -> S0

Does the epsilon mean that it cannot be LL(1)?

Comment: you may want to add a second tag to direct it around - for instance NLP

Comment: By your logic you would always choose `S0` when you saw 0. Since you never use up the 0 wouldn't you recurse forever into `S0` and never find epsilon?

Comment: So because S -> S0 -> S00 -> S000 -> e000 ?
Which is wrong because the epsilon should be like 000e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This grammar is not LL(1) just because it has a left recursion on it. When you will try to build the parser table, you will came up with a conflict.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser